# Grails: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: java, grails, groovy, java-home

I have tried to install Grails framework and command "grails" in terminal every time crashes. I am using Debian Squeeze and I set in `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile this`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22
export GRAILS_HOME="/home/snitch/grails"
export PATH=${PATH}:${GRAILS_HOME}/bin
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Any more error messages? usually grails will give more info when JAVA_HOME is incorrect

Comment: No, it's the only one error :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.22 
export JAVA_HOME 
GRAILS_HOME=/home/snitch/grails 
export GRAILS_HOME 
PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin 
export PATH
```

Comment: The answer helped me, though it wasn't exactly my solution of course because the path to java is different.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that `JAVA_HOME` points to a jdk, not just a jvm. See: http://www.grails.org/Installation.

You may need to add `${JAVA_HOME}/bin` to your `PATH` also.

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
export PATH=$GRAILS_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and you can test it from the commandline with

```
echo $PATH
```

and

```
java -version
```

Comment: No, doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why so secretive? How is it failing???